# How to partially overlay a circle with a third of a circle?

Tags: html, css

I want a picture circle which has a label in the lower half which has a background. I think I post a jsfiddle so that you can understand what I want : http://jsfiddle.net/Lf65Z/

So this is my css:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 1000px;
}

#labelbackground {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(165, 165, 165, 0.62);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
}
```

This gives me a background for 50% of the circle. But I want to overlay just something like 33% of the circle, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf65Z/1/

```
#labelbackground {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(165, 165, 165, 0.62);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1000px;
}
```

But as you can see its not really doing what I want... Is there any possibility to just cut off the 50% background, so that it keeps the right border-radius?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden;` to the container. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/deVRd/

**Edit**:
for case with slider you may use gradients. See http://jsfiddle.net/C7mc7/. Read more about CSS3 gradients [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) and easily create your own [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: Oh wow... that's want..Thanks a lot. So I can just put a square div behind it and I'm fine thanks!

Comment: Is there any possibility to exclude an element from the overflow hidden? I've got an element which is cut off now :/ (It's not in the fiddle)

Comment: Can you create a more detailed jsFiddle to see the whole situation?

Comment: For sure wait a second :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SE787/ It's without javascript but I think that's not necessary.

Comment: @Thunder, see edit section for your slider solution.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help!